# Creating two divs with a button

Tags: javascript, html, button, local-storage

I am creating a simple note editor that has two divs a heading and a body. I'm trying to add a new note by creating the two divs with a button. Such that when you click the button the new divs will be created with texts appended to it through localStorage. When I click the button none of the divs is added. here is the html

```
<div id ="heading" contenteditable="true">
</div>
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="addNote()" name="button">Add new Note</button>
```

here is the js

```
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = localStorage['title'] || 'Heading goes here';
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = localStorage['text'] || 'Body of text editor';

setInterval(function () {
localStorage['title'] = document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML;
localStorage['text'] = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

}, 1000);

function addNote() {
  const heading = document.createElement('div');
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  heading.id = "heading";
  content.id = "content";

localStorage['title'] = document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML;
localStorage['text'] = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

}
```

Comment: you are just creating the elements. You also have to append them somewhere into the DOM

Comment: how do I do that? I think this `document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = localStorage['title'] || 'Heading goes here';` takes care of that?

Comment: no this is just the local browser storage. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp have a look here

Answer (score 0):

your are missing to append the created elements to the dom (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) :

```
function addNote() {
  var heading = document.createElement('div');
  var content = document.createElement('div');
  heading.id = "heading";
  content.id = "content";
  document.getElementById("myDivs").appendChild(heading);
  document.getElementById("myDivs").appendChild(content);
}
```

and you will need to have an div with id `myDivs`

```
<div id="myDivs"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="addNote()" name="button">Add new Note</button>
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code.

1. Proper way to set `localStorage` is via `localStorage.setItem(key, val)`
2. You need to append your `DIVs` somewhere on your `HTML` page.
3. Also you need to handle your `setTimeout` properly.

Please find solution below

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="addNote()" name="button">Add new Note</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var intervalObj = null;
function addNote() {
  if(intervalObj) {
    clearInterval(intervalObj)
  }
  const heading = document.createElement('div');
  heading.setAttribute('contenteditable', true)
  heading.id = "heading";
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.setAttribute('contenteditable', true)
  content.id = "content";
  heading.innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('title') || 'Heading goes here';
  content.innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('text') || 'Body of text editor';
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].append(heading);
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].append(content);
  intervalObj = setInterval(function () {
    localStorage.setItem('title', document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML);
    localStorage.setItem('text', document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the setInterval function you can load the data using an onload function and update to local storage whenever the AddNote button is clicked.

Modify the html as follows:

```
<body onload="load()">
    <div id ="heading" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="content" contenteditable="true">

  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="addNote()" name="button">Add new Note</button>
</body>
```

And also you can modify your JS file as follows

```
function load() {
  var headingText = localStorage['title'] || 'Heading goes here';
  var bodyText = localStorage['text'] || 'Body of text editor';
  document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = headingText;
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = bodyText;
}
function addNote() {


localStorage['title'] = document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML;
localStorage['text'] = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

}
```